# OSMDroid not getting bonus pack import to show up

Tags: android, eclipse, osmdroid

I have a working map shown in my android app, but am not able to get the OSMBonusPack to work. I am working in Eclipse. I have all the required files noted (and setup) to have from here: https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/HowToInclude.

When I try and add:

```
KmlDocument kmlDocument = new KmlDocument();
        kmlDocument.parseUrl(cafires);
        FolderOverlay kmlOverlay = (FolderOverlay) kmlDocument.mKmlRoot
                .buildOverlay(this, map, null, null, kmlDocument);
```

Nothing will import related to OSMBonusPack. I have the latest release 4.9. I have also tried 4.8 just to see if that was the issue. When I manually type import org.osmdroid... the bonuspack is not in the list if clicking ctrl+space. I've cleaned my project and also closed and reopened eclipse.

Any suggestions?

EDIT::: I was able to get the OSMBonusPack to load using it as a library after I pulled the code from GITHUB here: https://github.com/grote/OSMBonusPack

Comment: We have to convert osmbonuspack.aar to jar file ?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
FolderOverlay kmlOverlay = (FolderOverlay)mKmlDocument.mKmlRoot.buildOverlay(map, defaultStyle, null, mKmlDocument);
```